# eigen3 arraywise matrix vector product for each column of matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, product, eigen3

I have an array and a vector:

```
ArrayXd m1(3, 1337); 
ArrayXd v1(1, 1337);
ArrayXd result(3, 1337);
```

now I want to multiply each row of `m1` with `v1`

(like if you would do `m1.*v1` in Matlab.

What I have by now is:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    result.row(i) = m1.row(i)*v1;
}
```

can this be done in some more elegant way using some eigen functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ArrayXXd m1(3,1337);
ArrayXXd v1(1,1337);
ArrayXXd result = m1 * v1.replicate(m1.rows(),1);
```

If efficiency is important, you should consider storing `m1` and `result` in an `Array<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>` and `v1` in a `Array<double, 1, Dynamic>`